# Microsoft All-in-One Media Keyboard not working at all with RPi 2

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, troubleshooting

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
 Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp. 
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514             Fast Ethernet Adapter
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

http://pastebin.com/kxE5ZWNv (keys)

http://pastebin.com/KwG7Vz2k (trackpad)

pastebin.com/63e74Qib (media keys)

I used lsusb and evtest to check whether the keyboard it registering withe the Pi at all. It is, but no keystrokes/trackpad movements result in text appearing, cursor moving, etc. Keyboard works fine on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04/Thinkpad t450s, including media keys.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Have you tried booting the pi while the keyboard in the USB slot? I have a keyboard which only has worked when It's plugged in before Raspbian booted.

Comment: Try the keyboard both with a tty(not X) and pts(under X). It may be an X11 issue

Comment: Hi Bryce, thanks for this. The keyboard's behaviour doesn't change when its booted with the dongle plugged in. I've also researched tty/pts but I'm going to have to admit my understanding isn't sophisticated enough to be able to do those tests without more specific instructions, do you know if there's a guide out there which could help me?

Comment: For what I have understood about pts/tty, maybe it's relevant that the Pi is running headless, being accessed via Vinagre

Comment: put the output of `dmesg` onto pastebin after rebooting the pi with the keyboard plugged in.

Comment: If you boot the pi, by default lightdm and X11 will be handling the keys of your physically attached keyboard keyboard. If X11 is not configured properly that might be a point of faliure. Try killing X remotely and then typing

Comment: What distro/kernel version are you using? Compare the kernel version(`uname -a`) on the pi with the version that the keyboard works on(on the laptop)

Comment: You may need to install a bluetooth daemon for this keyboard(it is bluetooth right?)

Comment: Think I have a solution: it was a VNC issue. I finally found a monitor to plug the Pi in, and found that what you see via the VNC and what you see on the monitor are two quite different things. And the keyboard works fine via a monitor. Thanks for your suggestions!